# Expandable List view Child click Listener

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-alertdialog

I have a pretty simple question. In my dialog which contains an exxpandable list view, when I click a child, I want to do some actions and return to the activity. My click events of `setOnChildClickListener()` and `setOnGroupClickListener()` are all working but my alertdialog doesn't close. I want to close my alertdialog on child click of the list and return to my activity. Can any one help?

Code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    TestActivity.this);

        ExpandableListView dialogExpandableListView = new ExpandableListView(
                this);
        dialogExpandableListView
                .setAdapter(new EfficienctExpandableAdapter(
                        this));
        dialogExpandableListView
                .setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView arg0,
                            View arg1, int arg2, int arg3, long arg4) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Log.d("skt", "clicked parent " + arg2 + " child "
                                + arg3);

                        return false;
                    }
                });

        dialogExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.d("skt", "group click --- clicked parent " + arg2);
                return false;
            }
        });

        builder.setView(dialogExpandableListView);

        builder.create();
        builder.show();
```

Comment: post some code.. it will helpful to find what you doing

Answer (score 0):

I think you started to show the Alertdialog here

```
    builder.setView(dialogExpandableListView); 
    builder.create();
    builder.show();
```

But you haven't canceled the alertView anywhere.

Try to cancel the alertView here

```
 @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView arg0,
                        View arg1, int arg2, int arg3, long arg4) {
                 Log.d("skt", "clicked parent " + arg2 + " child "
                             + arg3);
                 builder.cancel();
                 //or
                 builder.dismiss();
                 return false;

   }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I already tried that. It says to make a cast to DialogInterface. When I do that I get a ClassCastException

((DialogInterface) builder).dismiss(); is what I've done...
have you tried doing that?

Comment: I have tested and it didn't work. If you find a way to make it work please update.